# SwiftUI: Have the ImagePicker save photo and set the binding variable to true and update views across the system. saved photo and variable persistent

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I need the image picker to set a binding variable to True after an image is selected. After that image is selected, it needs to be saved. But after I select the image, the views changes. It isn't until I kill the app that the image and variable are changed back.

For the image picker, An error comes out "Instance member 'TrueBadge' of type 'PhotoPicker' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'PhotoPicker.Coordinator'"

Here's BadgeScreen View:

````
import Foundation

var PresentedBadge =  UIImage(systemName: "questionmark")!

func loadImage() -> UIImage {
    do {
        if let furl = fileURL {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: furl)
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
                return img
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)") // todo
    }
    return UIImage()
}

var IsDone = false

struct Badge: View {

    @Binding var TrueBadge: Bool //Need help switching this Binding to true
    @State private var ComplianceBadgeIsPicking =  UIImage(named: "BlankComplianceBadge")!
    @State private var isShwoingPhotoPicker = false
    @State private var ShowInstruction = false
    @State private var AlertToReplaceBade = false
   

    var body: some View {
        //The beginning
        if TrueBadge {
            
            Color("MainBadgeScreen")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .overlay(
                    VStack{
                        Text("Clearance Status")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .offset(y: -15)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("Vaccine Compliant")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .bold()
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                        Image(uiImage: ContentViewBadge)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .scaledToFit()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            AlertToReplaceBade.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "trash" )
                            Text("Remove")
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .offset(y: 13)
                        
                        
                        
                    }.alert(isPresented: $AlertToReplaceBade, content: {
                        Alert(title: Text("Are you sure you would like to remove your current badge?"),
                              message: Text("Remeber that this badge is and will be permanently removed"),
                              primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes"), action: {
                            
                                // Somehow need to remove the image and activate the UIImagePickerController
                          
                            
                        }), secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("No, I do not")))
                        
                    })

                )}
        else {
            Color("ExpiredBadgeScreen")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .overlay(
                    VStack{
                        
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.questionmark.fill")
                            .font(.system(size:150))
                            .offset(y: -10)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                        Text("Compliance Badge")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .offset(y: -2)
                            
                        
                        Text("You do not have a current vaccine compliant badge. Please upload one that shows you are vaccine compliant or within 'green' status")
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .frame(width: 270, height: 140, alignment: .center)
                            .offset(y: -26)
                        
                       
                        Button(action: {
                            ShowInstruction.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                            Text("How to upload")
                                .bold()
                                .font(.system(size:20))
                        }
                        .offset(y: -40)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            isShwoingPhotoPicker.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            Text("Upload Badge")
                                .bold()
                                .font(.system(size:20))
                        }
                        .offset(y: -10)

                    }.sheet(isPresented: $ShowInstruction, content: {
                        Instruction()
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShwoingPhotoPicker, content: {
                        PhotoPicker(TrueBadge: $TrueBadge, Badge: $ComplianceBadgeIsPicking)
                    })
                        .accentColor(.black)
                    
                )
        }
        //The End
    }


}

var ContentViewBadge = UIImage(systemName: "questionmark")!
var fileURL: URL?


func saveImage() {
    do {
        let furl = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("imageFile")
            .appendingPathExtension("png")
        fileURL = furl
        try ContentViewBadge.pngData()?.write(to: furl)
    } catch {
        print("could not create imageFile")
    }
}

struct PhotoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    //Since the Binding cannot be created above, I have no choice but to put it here
    @Binding var TrueBadge: Bool
    @Binding var Badge: UIImage
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        return picker
        
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(photoPicker: self)
        
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let photoPicker: PhotoPicker
        
        init(photoPicker: PhotoPicker){
            self.photoPicker = photoPicker
        }

        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage{
                photoPicker.Badge = image
                ContentViewBadge = photoPicker.Badge
                // This is where I am having trouble at. I am unable to change the Bool type of "TrueBadge" to true and have it stay on even after the application
                // Is killed
                // I also need the selected image to remain here. If i kill the application, the image is removed and the Boolean and set to false
                //Error is being created below
                TrueBadge = true
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}```

And here's MainScreen view:
```import SwiftUI
import SafariServices


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var ShowInstruction = false
    @State var ShowBadge = false
    @State var ShowPortal = false
    @State var ShowDetails = false
    @State var ViewAlert = false
    @State var TrueBadge = false
    

    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            Color("BackgroundMain")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .overlay(
                    VStack{
                        //Need the if Bool condition to set to true after an image is safe and the variable is set to true
                        if TrueBadge {
                            Button(action: {
                                ShowBadge.toggle()
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "doc.text.image")
                                    .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                                    .background(Color("MainBadgeScreen"))
                                    .cornerRadius(15)
                            }
                
                        }
                        else {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.ViewAlert = true
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "doc.text.image")
                                    .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                                    .background(Color("ExpiredBadgeScreen"))
                                    .cornerRadius(15)
                            }

                        }
                       
                    }
                        .alert(isPresented: $ViewAlert, content: {
                            Alert(title: Text("You agree to use this app responsibly?"), primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes"), action: {
                                ShowBadge = true
                            }), secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("No, I do not")))
                            
                        }))
                .sheet(isPresented: $ShowBadge, content: {
                    Badge(TrueBadge: $TrueBadge)
                })
                .navigationTitle("Home")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Menu {
                            Button(action: {
                                ShowPortal = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Student Health Portal")
                                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                ShowInstruction = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Instructions")
                                Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                ShowDetails = true
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                                Text("About")
                            }
                        }
                        
                    label: {
                    icon: do {
                        Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("WithSystem"))
                    }
                    }
                    }
                }
            
                .sheet(isPresented: $ShowPortal, content: {
                    safari()
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $ShowInstruction, content: {
                    Instruction()
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $ShowDetails, content: {
                    Details()
                })
        }
        .accentColor(Color(.label))
    }
    
    
    
    
    struct safari : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<safari>) -> SFSafariViewController{
            
            let controller = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://patientportal.bowiestate.edu/login_directory.aspx")!)
            return controller
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<safari>) {
            
        }
    }

}```
````

Comment: you should review this tutorial: 
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Comment: Thanks, but do you know of any ways to relieve the issues I’m having

Comment: This topic should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485475/i-am-unsure-why-my-imagepickercontroller-coordinator-is-not-triggering-didfinish.